# Interface and generic notations in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am starting with .net and read a couple chapters on generics and interfaces.  I see this in code and am not sure how I should read it:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IndexSequenceModel>> model
```

The above is a parameter to a method.  Can someone explain to me what that means?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a sequence of sequences. So for example, if you had a collection of customers and each customer had a number of orders, you could get an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Order>>` - one sequence of orders per customer.

Or as another example, imagine you had a `Batch` method - it could take a "flat" sequence and break it into fixed-size batches, where each batch is a sequence of items, and the return value is a sequence of batches.

Comment: Was your second paragraph a casual plug for MoreLINQ  ;)

Comment: @KennethK.: I *nearly* included a link for MoreLINQ, but didn't think it would be a good idea. I was definitely thinking of it though :)